# PHP code not running (XAMP(latest version))

Tags: php, html, web, server, xampp

I have checked the php.ini file for common default_mimetype="text.html".
And this is so strange because I it was working fine in earlier stages of my studies on the same machine. Using xampp 7.x

Comment: Can you confirm that your server is running without any problems and you directory of the PHP is inside the htdocs?

Comment: yes. Confirmed. I have ran a php check file located in the php directory as well.

Comment: Can you add the Error message here to identify the exact error?

Comment: Only html is returned. php is ignored completely,
<body>

Comment: Only html is displayed. PHP is ignored completely.
Here is an ideal version.
<body>
<?php
print 'hello folks';
?>
</body>
</html>